# Nix: Antiquote to a Set

Tags: nix

I there a good way to antiquote a value directly to a set?

In Nix, we can use antiquotation to select an attribute based on a variable:

```
let 
  x = { a = "V" ; };
  sel = "a";  
in 
  x."${sel}"

result> "V"
```

But what if instead, we want to select the set, `x`, based on the antiquotation?

```
let 
  x = { a = "V" ; };
  sel = "x";  
in
  "${sel}".a

result> (paraphrased) error: Expected a set but received a string.
```

Nix complains that it tried to retrieve attribute `a` from a set, but it wasn't given a set (`x`), it was given a string (`"x"`). I understand that we wouldn't want to generally coerce a string `"x"` into the in-scope value, `x`, but it seems weird to me that Nix wouldn't in this case where we are treating it specifically as a set. But I digress...

Anyway, I'd appreciate a demonstration of a simple pattern to overcome this problem. Or, better yet, a reusable construct such as `(toSet sel).a` that works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use a variable to pick another variable from the current scope.
The syntax you're using is for string interpolation, which will only ever return a string.
As far as I know, Nix does not provide a way to dynamically access the scope in such a way.

I don't expect that such a feature will be implemented, because such a construct seems quite fragile. Adding it to the language will make the language harder to reason about because it will be hard to tell whether a variable is used, or whether a string interpolation actually returns a string.

It's probably best to put all the things you might want `sel` to point to in a single attribute set. This will make the intent of the code clear to the reader.

```
let
  selectables = {
    x = { a = "V"; };
    y = { a = "W"; };
  };
  selector = "x";
in
  selectables.${selector}.a   # the quotes weren't necessary
```